# Docker host network container service access under Windows

Tags: docker, networking, port, accessibility, host

If I run docker container using the host network (`--network host`), for any services running in the container their exposed port can be directly accessed from host right?

I always thought so until I'm running docker container using the host network under Windows --

- The `ip a s eth0` shows that my container IP address is `192.168.65.3`
- The `route | awk '/^default/ { print $2 }'` gives `192.168.65.1`
- However, my host machine has an IP of `10.66.xx.xx`

I.e., the container IP address and host IP are completely different. Unlike what the https://www.metricfire.com/blog/understanding-dockers-net-host-option/ says.

Anyway, if I'm running any services in the container, how to expose their port so that they can be directly accessed from host? (I thought with host network (`--network host`), you no longer need to map port from container to host)

thx

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host networking is not supported on Windows:

> The `host` networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.

https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

I would suggest trying the `-p` option to `docker run`, since that is supported on Windows.

Alternately, one forum user [suggests](https://forums.docker.com/t/does-the-run-option-network-host-work-on-docker-for-windows/45773) using VirtualBox in bridged mode to install Linux, which can then use host networking. YMMV.

Comment: What do you mean? https://paste.debian.net/plainh/bcc85bfb

Comment: My mistake, removed.