# Provide services from within docker container to host under Windows

Tags: linux, docker, networking, service, debian-based

Continue on with [Docker host network container service access under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63210284/),

I am having a hard time trying to expose services in the Linux container (i.e. their ports) so that they can be directly accessed from host.

If the host is Linux, I know a whole spectrum of tools to troubleshoot the situation. But when it comes to Windows host, I don't know where to start and how to troubleshoot step by step.

I'm starting `docker` with `-p 3999:3999` on Windows, and within the Linux container I'm starting a Go based web service listening on `0.0.0.0:3999`. These are the things I have been doing without any issue when the host is Linux. Now the only difference is,

- The host is now Windows
- It may not have any relevance, but the Windows is using corporation's transparent proxy.

How can I troubleshoot the situation step by step?

**Update:**

I don't have firewall installed --

```sh
% iptables -L
-bash: iptables: command not found

% sudo iptables -L
sudo: iptables: command not found

% ufw status
-bash: ufw: command not found

% dpkg -l | grep fire || echo no firewall  found
no firewall found

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
Release:        testing
Codename:       bullseye
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation. I deployed react service in the container in the centos 8. The host from which I was trying to access the service was windows. I was unable to access the service from my windows host browser. And stopping the firewall did the thing for me.

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Bhargav11, mine is not a problem on the Linux side, as I don't have firewall installed. See updated OP. Thanks anyway, upvoting!